# Cassandra insert performance on a single node C APIs

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, nosql

I am trying to profile cassandra on a single node cluster to see how much one node can handle inserts and then add more node as per this result.
I have changed certain parameters in cassandra.yaml. They are as follows.

```
memtable_offheap_space_in_mb: 4096
memtable_allocation_type: offheap_buffers
concurrent_compactors: 8
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 32768
concurrent_reads: 64
concurrent_writes: 128
concurrent_counter_writes: 128
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 200000
```

Cassandra node: JVM heap size 12GB

I have added these parameters to the cassandra C++ driver APIs
`cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io(cluster, 8);`
`cass_cluster_set_core_connections_per_host(cluster,8);`
`cass_cluster_set_write_bytes_high_water_mark(cluster,32768000);`
`cass_cluster_set_pending_requests_high_water_mark(cluster,16384000);`

With these parameters i get a write speed of 13k/sec with data size of 1250 bytes.
I wanted to know am i missing out on anything in terms of parameter tuning to achieve a better performance.

Cassandra DB node details:
VM
CentOs 6
16GB RAM
8 cores. And is running on a separate box from the machine i am pumping data.

Any insight will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, designing a good data model is more important than any of that.  What does your table look like?

Comment: Hi aaron. My data model is simple.. It has one key space and inside that it has one table in which it can have 95 - 100 columns. Right now I have 96.

Comment: include version. ssd? disk is king in db world. Are you making requests in parallel or serially (does latency of request impact throughput?).

Comment: I dont know for sure if that is SSD because its a remote server.The cassandra versions is 3.0.7.1158. I am writing parallely. Multiple threads writing. I set callbacks for the future after execute so its async.